# Section 21 notice if the tenant doesn't have a valid address for the landlord

Tags: united-kingdom, rental-property, rent, tenant, tenancy-rules

I have been given a section 21 notice but I don't have an address in England and Wales to which I can service documents to, as specified by [section 48](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1987/31/section/48). Does this invalidate the section 21? The agent dissolved half way through the tenancy. The address specified in the contract for which to serve notice etc, is an address abroad. Obviously a mistake made by an incompetent letting agent. I have only just fouund out I could have been witholding rent all this time... but too late for that.

If I want to demand to know the address of my landlord, I can wwrite to him abroad, but I won't be able to claim proof of receipt for letters abroad... and sending recorded delivery abroad is exepensive so would rather not do that. So how can I reliably ask for his address? It's a bit of a chicken and egg scenario.

Comment: Where were you sending the money, if you don't know how to get a hold of them, but didn't withhold rent? Send the letter where you sent the money.

Comment: @Putvi bank transfer to his barclays account (a UK bank)

Comment: Subpoena the bank to find him then.

Comment: @Putvi i've never heard of anyone being able to request personal info like that from a  bank? How do I do it, do I just show them my tenancy agreement and be like "hey, look, your client who is my landlord, is in breach of section 48, can i have his address from you."

Comment: You may not be able to get it by just asking, but if you get a subpoena through the court they would turn it over.

Comment: @Putvi i can't find any info in the uk how to do this. Subpoena seems to mean 'witness summons' in UK law. Either way, it all seems quite costly and time consuming, i'm wondering instead if I can get out of a section 21 notice as a result of not having a valid address for my landlord, for which to serve notices, etc.

Comment: It would be time consuming, but most stuff in court normally is. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Putvi please note the jurisdiction on questions, as it introduces context - in the UK we don't have subpoenas, we have court summons and court rulings and court warrants and court orders. If you want to require the bank to give up information, then here you would need a Norwich Pharmacal order - asking for a subpoena would simply get you laughed at for watching too much American TV.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you believe that the address abroad is incorrect? It's entirely possible that the landlord might live overseas. Also, can you confirm that the section 21 paperwork contained no contact details at all?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff The address abroad is not incorrect, but section 48 specifies I must be given an address in England and Wales, otherwise I can't sue him for anything (which I do). Also, the section 21 was given via email, not post.

Comment: @Ashley why do you think you could have been withholding rent "all this time"?

Comment: @Moo see the link to section 48

Comment: @Ashley fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been given a section 21 [of the Housing Act 1988] notice but I don't have an address in England and Wales to which I can service documents to, as specified by section 48 [of the Landlord and Tenant Act 1987]. Does this invalidate the section 21?

According to an article  on [Landlord Law Blog](https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2016/02/26/is-a-section-21-notice-invalid-if-it-is-served-from-abroad/) which addresses this very question, no:

> Section 21 notices must comply with the requirements of section 21 of the Housing Act 1988 and the courts are very strict on this. However, I cannot see anywhere in the section a requirement that the notice must give an address for the landlord which is in England or Wales.

The article also confirms one aspect of the question, in that:

> There are situations where the landlord’s address is significant. For example rent is not due unless a landlord gives an address for service of documents in England / Wales.

The question also states:

> If I want to demand to know the address of my landlord, I can [write] to him abroad, but I won't be able to claim proof of receipt for letters abroad... and sending recorded delivery abroad is [expensive] so would rather not do that. So how can I reliably ask for his address?

I'm taking this (and subsequent comments) to mean that OP does have a reliable way of contacting the landlord - but that the landlord is in breach of section 48 because no address has been made available which is in England or Wales.

So the answer seems to be: assuming the Section 21 notice is otherwise valid, the fact that the landlord has provided an invalid address doesn't change that. However, it appears that no rent is due until a valid address is provided (though note that once a valid address is provided, [**all** withheld rent is then due](https://www.landlordlawblog.co.uk/2014/05/29/a-tenants-right-to-know-his-landlords-address/).)

It is possible that the landlord has made an honest mistake, and didn't realise that the current absence of a letting agent has left them in breach of the law. So it may be worth contacting the landlord to point this out, so they can appoint a new letting agent.

*Please note: withholding rent when it is legally due can have serious consequences. I am not a legal professional, so before taking any action, I would seriously recommend talking to an expert.*

Also relevant:

- [this guide](https://england.shelter.org.uk/housing_advice/eviction/section_21_eviction/how_to_check_a_section_21_notice_is_valid) on how to check if a Section 21 notice is valid. Note that it doesn't mention anything about the landlord's address having to be in England or Wales.
- [Information about landlords' identity and address](http://england.shelter.org.uk/legal/security_of_tenure/basic_principles_security_of_tenure/Information_about_a_landlords_identity).

Comment: as annoying as it is, this answer seems the most correct, thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi as you already know landlords are legally required by law to provide an address in the UK. It does not have to be the private address of the landlord. The landlord can opt to use the letting agent, accountants address.

For section 8 Notice no rent is payable until such time the landlord is compliant under section 48 of the 1987 Act.

However for the section 21 notice (Form 6A – For England) it should an address for the landlord, if not it may be deemed invalid.

If you do need detailed advice I have found the British Landlords Association and Shelter both very good. They are both not for profit and give free advice. You obtain their info by visiting [the BLA](https://thebla.co.uk).